# Как определить причину мерцания красного цвета на экране?

Tags: экран, железо

Пробовал всякие программки для битых пикселей, в течении часа, никакого результата.
Как можно точно определить в чём проблема?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: методом исключения - заменить видяху, затем монитор, ну или наоборот. для первой заменить дровишки и проверить температурный режим и питание.

Comment: Замените провод, в том числе провод питания монитора.